# Use of "I" in mathematics papers

Tags: article-writing

Some people consider the use of "I" in a paper to be a great evil.  Others, however, consider the use of the passive voice to be an even greater evil.

I will be presenting a paper at a competition, and I don't know what the judges prefer.  If I don't want to make anyone mad, which convention is safer to follow?

Comment: Even single authors oftentimes write "we"

Comment: @mathse True, but I want to make certain the judges know that I did the work...

Comment: If you want to make certain the judges know you did the work, announce at the beginning that you did the work. That should settle that.

Comment: Plus, in a less formal environment, the "I" is ok, I think, if not excessively made us of. E.g. here: http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mampsj/Binomial.pdf

Comment: A "competition"...of papers? That bewilders me...

Comment: I try to reserve "we/us" to indicate "myself, and you, the reader, who joins me on this intellectual adventure", in constructions like "We take $\alpha$ to be ..." or "Let us embed the figure in $n$-dimensional space ..."; mixing that usage with the Royal We can be a little confusing (but I don't believe it's *too* big of a deal). You can always use "this author" to signify your specific contribution, with @Gerry's suggestion to get it out of the way early: "The following discusses this author's research into (whatever)...". In any case ... Doesn't the competition suggest a style guide?

Comment: Come to think of style guides: ["Mathematical Writing" by Knuth](http://jmlr.org/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf) is a worthwhile (and free!) read. The sixth "especially important" point (page 2) addresses the use of "we", stating that "[The usage] is *not* a formal equivalent of 'I'.".

Comment: I agree with Blue, as an undergrad, I have never collaborated with anyone, my proofs and assignments are always by myself alone. However, I always use we, and use it as "myself and the reader." I write my proofs as if someone was going to read along and work along to be convinced, that's why I do that.

Comment: Ok.  But should I stick to passive voice in the abstract?

Comment: @user1577636: Perhaps if you post the abstract, we can offer more-specific advice. By the way, you might also browse [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com); for instance, ["What to use instead of academic 'we' when describing an experiment?"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15344/what-to-use-instead-of-academic-we-when-describing-an-experiment/16071#16071).